# Gaining intuitive understanding of the formula for present value of an ordinary annuity

Tags: annuity

I have a question about the formula to calculate the present value of an ordinary annuity  in the text book "business Finance 12E". The page is at the end of this question.

The formula is:

Pi = (C / i) * ( 1 - 1/(1+i)^n )

Let's imagine a simple example, where the interest `i` is 8%pa and we get `n` 4 payments `C` of $5000 each. So, $5000 + $5000 + $5000 + $5000 (4 payments, once every year, starting from year 1).

I know in advance that the present value of the annuity is 16560.63.

I want to gain a proper deep understanding of this formula.

So, I will break it down.

- `( 1 - 1/(1+i)^n )`. For this one, I will focus first on `1/(1+i)^n`. Correct me if I am wrong: this represents a multiplier which will return the discounted value of the LAST instalment. In this case, it will be 1/(1+0.08)^4 = 0.7350. The last annuity in the last period, once discounted, is indeed $3675.15. Since there is that "1 - " in front of it, the actual result is 1 - 0.735 = 0.265. What does it represent? In words, I would put it as "The amount of value "lost" when discounting the last instalment C4". This value in this example is $1325. NOTE: From a "intuitive" perspective, this makes no sense. Why would the loss of value from the *last* instalment provide anything meaningful? Anyhow, the result of this section in words is ***The percentage loss of the last instalment after discounting. In this case, it's 0.265 (or, 26.5%)***
- (C / i). In this case, C is 5000. So, 5000/0.08 is 62500. I am struggling to understand the intuitive significance of meaning of this number. If you multiply by 0.08, you get the 80% of the number. If you multiply by 1.08, you get the original value PLUS 80% of its original value. Here, we are dividing by a percentage, so the meaning of that 62500 is this: ***The starting number that will give you the C instalment amount when applying the interest `i`***. Basically, 62500 * 0.08 = $5000.

So, in the end, I need to make heads of tails of:

- To figure out the present value of 4 instalments of $5000 over 4 years with an 8% interest, all I have to do is simple: calculate 26.5% (total difference when discounting of the last instalment C) of the instalment value inflated by... NO IT MAKES NO SENSE.

## BUT I HAVE A BETTER IDEA

I am looking at this wrong. The same formula can be written as:

Pi = C * ( ( 1 - 1/(1+i)^n ) / i )

Now, on one hand it's just semantics. But the intuitive advantage is that if `( 1 - 1/(1+i)^n )` is ***The percentage of the loss of the  last instalment when discounted. In this case, it's 0.265 (or, 26.5%)***, the whole thing *divided by i* (the interest, 0.08) is **at least something that finds the ratio of two values *at least of the same type (percentages)*.** The result in this case is 3.3125, which is the "magic" number which, when multiplied by C, gives us the present value of the 4 instalments C with i being 8%.

We seem to be multiplying one instalment by the ratio between (a) the percentage loss of the last instalment after discounting and (b) the interest rate applied.

I still don't quite understand why or why the other instalments don't see to matter, from an intuitive perspective.

Am I getting closer to an intuitive understanding of this formula? Or am I getting it all horribly wrong?

[image]

Comment: I'm not the person who downvoted, but I'd guess that for whomever did it was some combination of no obvious question being asked, plus the fact that you appear to have posted a very similar question just a few hours before.

Comment: Look at the other question -- one of the people helping actually recommended I post another question on the correct formula. The question is completely different as it focusses on a different formula. And I DID ask a very specific question -- what the heck the formula means from an intuitive perspective. I also put down all of my reasoning and research, to show that I wasn't just asking the question.

Comment: So, we want a "portion" of the perpetual annuity. The present value of the first 4 payments represent 26.5% of the perpetual annuity's present value, the rest is 73.5% of it. The "interesting" part is that the present value of the fourth payment is 73.5% of the full instalment value, SO we use THAT to figure out the slice we want. But... is there an intuitive reason, mathematically speaking, on why the "loss" of the 4th payment's C4 over the full instalment value (26.5%) is the same as the percentage of the present value of the first four payments over the total perpetual present value?

Comment: I finally got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the annuity of finite duration as the difference of two *perpetual annuities*: (i) one starts immediately and (ii) the other starts after $n$ time steps.
The present value of the immediate perpetual annuity (i) is $C/i$ and the delayed perpetually annuity is a fraction of (i), discounted by the factor $(1+i)^{-n}$.

Comment: Oh my thank you thank you. I am trying my best to understand this part: "the delayed perpetually annuity is a fraction of (i), discounted by the factor $(1+i)^{-n}$."  -- probably because I haven't yet studied perpetual annuities. I fully undetrstand the first formula `C/i`.

Comment: FYI. Your text calls the immediate perpetual  (i) an "ordinary perpetuity". The delayed version (ii) is an income stream in which each payment is delayed in time by $n$ steps. So each payment in (ii) is worth a fraction of its counterpart in (i). That fractional amount is called its discounted value. Your text should have worked examples.

Comment: That's very interesting: `(5000/i) - (5000/i)/(1 + i)^4 =  16560.63`. Discounting to delay a perpetual annuity, neat.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking about this wrong. If you are thinking about values of ordinary annuities, forget the formula. Pull out a financial calculator or google financial calculator on Google.

You have PV (Present Value), N (Number of Periods), I (Rate), PMT (Payments), and FV (future value). You can solve for any of the values if you have all the rest.

Let's say the question is what's the Future Value of an annuity, with an initial value of $10,000, a rate of 17%, 5 periods, and 0 ongoing payments. So the initial value means you paid 10k for it (Plug -10,000 in your financial calculator). You are going to receive 17 pct of that ($1700) each period (plug 17 in I for interest rate), and it gets added to the 10k (the present value) each compounding period. After the second period is over, you are going to get .17 * $11700 (the 10k plus the 1700 in interest you received on the first period multiplied by .17), and so on. That's how compounding interest works. So at the end of 5 periods you are going to have roughly 19k-20k (that's the future value)(do the calc on the calculator and you'll get the precise answer. I'm just trying to show you how it works.

That is what those formulas are trying to say. Use a financial calculator to grasp the concept and play around with the numbers. The formula is too busy, but that is what the concept is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the main issue here is that I am trying to understand the maths beneath it -- the intuitive "why" of the formula from a mathematical perspective. I am DEFINITELY overthinking it... but I can't help it, that's how my brain is wired :D

Comment: Like I said forget the formula. You will never use it. If you need to memorize it for a test go for it. But those are the principles I outlined. Use a financial calculator for these problems. Learn what the formula is doing and how it is applied to real life, ie the financial calculator example, compounding interest, how to solve for an interst rate, or FV with your calculator, use it in real life (I do all the time), and move on with your life : )

Answer (score 0):

The formula is not very intuitive but the its construction is.  In an ordinary annuity the payment is made at the end of each period, as would be the case with a loan repayment.  The OP's example is 4 payments of $5000.  Relative to the initial 'present' value, the first payment at the end of year 1 would include 1 year's interest, so its net present value (NPV) is `5000/(1 + 0.08) = 4629.63`.  Likewise for the remaining payments:

```
1st payment of $5000 ... NPV = 5000/(1 + 0.08)^1 =  4629.63
2nd payment of $5000 ... NPV = 5000/(1 + 0.08)^2 =  4286.69
3rd payment of $5000 ... NPV = 5000/(1 + 0.08)^3 =  3969.16
4th payment of $5000 ... NPV = 5000/(1 + 0.08)^4 =  3675.15
                                                   --------
                                      Total NPV  = 16560.63
```

A summation representing the total NPV is straightforward to understand

[image: summation]

but the formula produced by [algebraic induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1039786/119821) (below) is generally not intuitively obvious, except in this case by [MathSensei's answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/158107/11768).

[image: induction]

The *process* of induction is intuitive but its results often are not.

The induction process for a general case `Σ 1/r^k` is sketched below.

[image]

Relating this to the OP's example

```
i = 0.08
C = 5000
b = 4
a = 1
r = (1 + i)
```

[image: example]